# Getting error in uploading network member group object in salesforce

Tags: community, permission-sets, campaign-member

I am trying to upload `permissionset` id and `networkid` to networkmembergroup but getting this error.

> duplicate value found: `<unknown>` duplicates value on record with id:
>   `<unknown>`

How can I publish or remove builder from community, just want to see manage link?